# What are some of the most important results from "Implicit computational complexity" theory?

Tags: complexity-theory

I just found out about [implicit computational complexity theory](https://www.cs.rice.edu/~sc40/obt15/mazza.pdf). It seems very interesting. I would like to know more about it.

For me to get an overview of the results of the field, what are roughly the most important results? Or what are the most important papers I should look at to get a good sense of the most important contributions?